# How to get Image height and width issue in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to get the height and width of an image in windows phone...but there are few syntax errors

how should i do this?

```
        int hight = image1.ActualHeight;
        int width = image1.ActualWidth;
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(image1.Image);
        BitmapImage newImg = new BitmapImage(hight,width);
```

Comment: what is your error and at which line?

Comment: errors in all the lines.unable to use ActualHegiht n ActualWidth then again errors in brackets

Comment: One of the errors is that ActualWidth and ActualHeight are double values. Use double for the local variables or cast the values to int. Provide more information about the usage of image1 and when you're trying to execute the code you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create an image,

```
<Image x:Name="image1" Source="myPicture.png" />
```

And then you can access it in your code behind

```
double height = image1.ActualHeight;
double width = image1.ActualWidth;
```

And there is no constructor for BitmapImage class which takes the arguments that you are passing. You can create a new BitmapImage in either of the following ways

```
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri("myPicture.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

or

```
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
bmp.UriSource = new Uri("myPicture.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

or

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = image1.Source as BitmapImage;
```

Hope this clears your doubt

Comment: yes most of my doubts are clear..but i still dont get the 
`bmp.PixelHeight = (int)height;
bmp.PixelWidth = (int)width;`

Comment: Updated my answer, I forgot one thing here PixelHeight and PixelWidth properties of BitmapImage are readonly properties. If you have any further doubt, let me know